# Extract contents under separate sections from a webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Below picture shows the html structure of the contents I want to pull from a website, and the code is also listed below the picture. I can't seem to find a solution to extract different information under the master class, allow me to explain it further.[image]

Example 1:

```
<li id="361821" class="list-group-item te-stream-item"><div class="te-stream-title-div"><a class="te-stream-title" href="/austria/balance-of-trade"><b>Austria Trade Deficit Widens in September</b></a><div class="pull-right"><a class="label small bg-primary te-stream-country" href="/stream?c=austria">Austria</a>&nbsp;<a class="label small te-stream-category" href="/stream?i=balance+of trade">Balance of Trade</a></div></div>The trade gap in Austria rose to EUR 1.38 billion in September of 2022 from EUR 1.02 billion a year ago. Imports surged 20.5% year-on-year to EUR 19.03 billion, mainly boosted by purchases of machinery &amp; vehicles (18.6%) while exports increased at a softer 19.6% to EUR 17.65 billion, on higher shipments of machinery &amp; vehicles (18.4%) and processed goods (17.9%). In the first nine months of the year, the country's trade deficit widened to EUR 13.84 billion from EUR 8.61 billion in the same period the year before. "However, the increase in international trade values is largely due to the rise in import and export prices, while the volumes were often declining. The value of gas imports, for example, increased by a whopping 132.7% in the period from January to September compared to the first three quarters of the previous year, although the volume of imports declined by more than 41.4 % in the same period,” said Statistics Austria Director General Tobias Thomas.<br><small>10 minutes ago</small></li>
```

Example 2:

```
<li id="361846" class="list-group-item te-stream-item te-stream-item-2"><div class="te-stream-title-div"><a class="te-stream-title-2" href="/commodity/crude-oil"><b>Crude Oil Hits Lowest Since December 2021</b></a><div class="pull-right"><a class="label small bg-primary te-stream-country" href="/stream?c=commodity">Commodity</a></div></div>WTI crude futures were trading around the $73 per barrel mark, the lowest since December 2021, as sentiment remained clouded by worries about weak global demand. Advanced economies, especially the US and Europe, are witnessing a drop in manufacturing activity due to tightening financial conditions. At the same time, sluggish Chinese customs data compounded fears about the global economy's health. Still looking for the demand side but offering some respite to investors, China has been dialing back coronavirus-related restrictions following widespread protests. On the supply front, OPEC+ decided to stick to their existing policy of reducing oil output by 2 million barrels a day from November through 2023. Investors were also assessing the impact of the latest sanctions on Russia, including a price cap and a European Union embargo on seaborne imports of Russian oil.<br><small>7 minutes ago</small></li>
```

The contents I want to pull is:

1. News Headlines (this is under `a` class='te-stream-title')
2. News Categories (this is under `div` class='pull-right', but get_text() won't get both categories as there could be multiple categories under 1 news)
3. News Content (this is under the master class `div` class='list-group-item te-stream-item') but if I `find_all` then `get_text()` it not only returns the content, but also returns `10 minutes ago` which is after the `br`, I would like contents as well as that 10 minutes ago to be pulled separately.

The master class I believe is the `list-group-item te-stream-item`, and if I use `soup.find_all('li', class_='list-group-item te-stream-item')`, it captures all of the sub-classes including news headlines, news contents, and news categories. My question is how to get to the next step to extract those information separately? So that it can later turn into a dataframe with rows as different news, with 4 columns (news headlines; news contents; news category; updated time)

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily, provide code over images. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Would be great, thanks.

Comment: For every component I want to extract, I use separate `find_all`'s, preferably the innermost HTML tag needed. In this case, e.g., that would be `te-stream-title` for the News headline, `soup.find_all('a', class_='te-stream-title')`. Otherwise, if we use 'master class', the text has to be parsed using our script.

Comment: @HedgeHog I have now added the code under the image, apology for not including it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is always the same you could go with [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) to extract the strings:

```
data = [dict(zip(['title','country','category','content','time'],e.stripped_strings)) for e in soup.select('li.list-group-item')]

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | title | country | category | content | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Austria Trade Deficit Widens in September | Austria | Balance of Trade | The trade gap in Austria rose to EUR 1.38 billion in September of 2022 from EUR 1.02 billion a year ago... | 10 minutes ago |

In case the pattern is not thes same you have to select your elements more specific:

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
html='''
<li id="361821" class="list-group-item te-stream-item">
    <div class="te-stream-title-div">
        <a class="te-stream-title" href="/austria/balance-of-trade"><b>Austria Trade Deficit Widens in September</b></a>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="label small bg-primary te-stream-country" href="/stream?c=austria">Austria</a>&nbsp;<a class="label small te-stream-category" href="/stream?i=balance+of trade">Balance of Trade</a>
        </div>
    </div>The trade gap in Austria rose to EUR 1.38 billion in September of 2022 from EUR 1.02 billion a year ago. Imports surged 20.5% year-on-year to EUR 19.03 billion, mainly boosted by purchases of machinery &amp; vehicles (18.6%) while exports increased at a softer 19.6% to EUR 17.65 billion, on higher shipments of machinery &amp; vehicles (18.4%) and processed goods (17.9%). In the first nine months of the year, the country's trade deficit widened to EUR 13.84 billion from EUR 8.61 billion in the same period the year before. "However, the increase in international trade values is largely due to the rise in import and export prices, while the volumes were often declining. The value of gas imports, for example, increased by a whopping 132.7% in the period from January to September compared to the first three quarters of the previous year, although the volume of imports declined by more than 41.4 % in the same period,” said Statistics Austria Director General Tobias Thomas.<br><small>10 minutes ago</small>
</li>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []
# data = [dict(zip(['title','country','category','content','time'],e.stripped_strings)) for e in soup.select('li.list-group-item')]
for e in soup.select('li.list-group-item'):
    data.append({
        'headline':e.a.text,
        'category':e.div.div.text,
        'content': e.div.next_sibling,
        'date':e.small.text
    })
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | headline | category | content | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Austria Trade Deficit Widens in September | Austria Balance of Trade | The trade gap in Austria rose to EUR 1.38 billion in September of 2022 from EUR 1.02 billion a year ago... | 10 minutes ago |

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works beautifully but with 1 problem though. Sometimes the news has only 1 category with no country, I have added the 2nd example in my question. So using your current script would return commodity to country instead of category.

Comment: That would be handled by the second example in my answer, where you have to select your elements specific.